# WebForms passing ClientID through a custom attribute

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We need to pass a client id of the current control to the child control, but we don't get it rendered, here is how we referenced the child control:

```
<uc:ChildrenControl ParentID="<%= ClientID %>" ID="EvuLieferbilanzkreiseListComponent" runat="server"></uc:ChildrenControl>
```

My output is `<%= ClientID %>` as string. How do I render the ClientID in my custom attribute? I also tried using **Bindable** attribute, but it didn't bind, ate least not on **Page_Load**. In which event should I be able to get the value of a bindable attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare `ParentID` as a public property in the ascx file?

```
public string ParentID { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = ParentID;
}
```

You can then set that property in the code behind of the parent aspx page.

```
EvuLieferbilanzkreiseListComponent.ParentID = ClientID;
```